# How to access my MongoDB instance from my project to my xunit test project class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb

I would like to mention that I have started learning how to build apis in asp net core 2.1 from microsoft's official documentation and I'm a beginner at this.

I have taken a sample task of building an api for a simple employee achievement form with MongoDB as my server, and have done documentation with Swashbuckle and currently stuck in unit testing my controller methods with xunit while i run my tests it returns me error:

> Message: System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have tried debugging my unit tests and I have found that every time my database instance "_empModel" returns null. Why does this happen?

What is the proper way to access this mongoDb instance in my xunit project to perform my tests?

Here is the link of my code snapshots: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jydiyuO_rSbx-2PXK0ZP8YoF8ho55avx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You would normally mock out dependencies when unit testing. You only want to test the code within the method being tested, not the code that gets called by that method and so on. Do a google for Unit Test and Moq and you should find plenty of good examples to help you.

Comment: thanks for the reply this is some new concept for me,i will try to google it,it will be a great help if u can suggest me some links for what you have mentioned :), and also i thought i need to get access to the database since only then my services would return something to my controller methods which will return some response to me

Comment: Something like this: http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Mocking-in-NET-Core-Tests-with-Moq but really google xunit and moq and you'll get a heap of results and should find one that makes sense to you.

Comment: The idea of unit testing is to test a single unit of code. If you don't mock out dependencies, then if the test fails you can't be sure if it was the code under test that had an issue, or the dependency. So test your controller code independentlly, your services code independently, and your mongo db logic independently. If you want to test all 3 together then you create an integration test and set everything up appropriately before running.
Ideally in a project you'd have many unit tests covering as much code as possible, and then a few integration tests making sure they all work together.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying me on this concept of unit testing and integration testing , i will try the link u have given  and google some more if needed.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a null is that in your unit tests you're calling the parameterless constructor of EmployeeServices, and you create your empModel in the constructor where you pass in config. You could get around this by having a config file in your test project and passing it in, but as mentioned in the comment to your post, you should be mocking out the services in your controller anyway.

If you do want to test the whole stack (integration testing), then instead of mocking you need to instantiate and and pass everything in appropriately.

Comment: sorry for not mentioning that but i already know that iam calling to the parameterless constructor, can u please guide me on how can i have config file in my test project and pass it in or if i can create my empModel in my parameterless constructor.

Comment: If you create an appsettings.json file in your test project it should be picked up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

so i have tried this method

created new json file named xunittests.json in xunit project, inside which i declared my "ConnectionString"

then i declared new config variable inside my class constructor something like this

public UnitTest1()

```
    {

        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("xunittest.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true).Build();

        _empTestServices = new EmployeeServices(config);

        _empTestController = new EmpController(_empTestServices);

    }
```

this has provided me access to my databaseinstance since now iam calling the non-empty EmployeeServices(Iconfiguration config) constructor which had the _empModel

but then again my unit tests are getting error like

Message: Assert.IsType() Failure

Expected: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.OkObjectResult

Actual:   (null)

now iam looking into it wish me luck XD